# Find initial value of a XOR list

Tags: c++, cryptography, xor

I've a pool of numbers and from these one number X has been XORed with all the others. From these comparisons the minimum XOR values are stored in a list in a sorted format.

How can I retrieve X ?

e.g.

```
List: { 3, 2, 1, 0, 15, 14, 13, 12 }
Looking for X so that:
X ^ 3 < X ^ 2 < X ^ 1 <... < X ^ 12
```

Might not be only one X or even none X. Is there any way to revert the process of a XOR when we don't know the initial value and the result of it but just it's comparative values? How can this be solved efficiently given we know the whole pool of numbers?

Comment: Too vague. If you can provide a sample input/output we may investigate.

Comment: Also note that the binary XOR is commutative. i.e. `a XOR b` equals to `b XOR a`.

Comment: Do you know the contents of the initial pool?

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, the pool is known.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't.

XOR is a really special operation. Its traits makes it impossible to figure out anything given only one of the operands, or the result.

If `A xor B == C`, then we have all the other five expressions:

- `C xor A == B`
- `B xor C == A`
- `C xor B == A`
- `A xor C == B`
- `B xor A == C`

If you see this, you should know it's impossible to get one value from another. Two is always needed for the third one.

Comment: Does the ordering constraint make a difference?  That's the interesting part of the question.

Comment: @TobySpeight Absolutely not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much on the outputs you have.  The problem might be underconstrained, giving many possible X values.  Or it might be impossible (no X satisfies the constraints).

One approach would be to pair values that differ only in the most-significant bit.  If the smaller of each pair appears before the larger, the MSB must be 0; if the larger appears first, then the MSB must be 1.

With that knowledge, we can consider pairs that differ only in the first two bits, and so on.

Comment: this means that I've to compare the numbers of the list with the whole pool? I was looking for a O(N^2) solution.

Comment: No, I mean pairs of values you find in the list.  In the example, we have `3` and `1` that differ only in the 2¹ bit.  `3` appears before `1`, so bit 1 of `X` must be set.  And so on.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, please? and how can I find the X on this way?

Comment: I'm reluctant to show further reasoning with this, on the basis that you haven't shown any evidence of your own progress - spoon-feeding solutions isn't why I'm here.

Comment: My solution was to find XORs of all the pool and then having the list to check the closest ones. But ofc it's very insufficient, therefore I'm here to ask for some help on the bits manipulation

Answer (score 0):

If certain conditions were true in the output, the value of X could be determined fairly efficiently.

For example:
If the value 15 were in the output array, then you would know that X is a binary complement of one of the other numbers. Also, if the value 0 were in the output array, you would know that this was the result of X being XORed with itself.

A general algorithm with an efficient time complexity would be difficult, however.